# String to long: error : number format Exception:for Input String "3.1"?

Tags: java, string, long-integer

My String result is: 3.1

I want to convert it into long :

I use some code like :

```
String txt_capplot="3.1";
Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(txt_capplot));
```

After Execute It made some error like:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "3.1"
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long is like integer it cant have decimal on them, but it will round it off.

**solution:**

you need to parse it to `double` first and then `cast` it to `long`.

**sample:**

```
    String s = "3.1";
    double d = Double.valueOf(s);
    long l = (long) d;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `long` does not contains decimal fractions, So need to convert your `String` to `double` and then the `long`.

You should try this one line solution :

```
Double.valueOf(txt_capplot).longValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

Long doesn't have a decimal part so you need to decide if you want to round it or truncate it. This code shows both

```
package se.wederbrand.stackoverflow;

public class ConvertToLong {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "3.6";
        double d = Double.parseDouble(s);
        long truncated = (long) d;
        long rounded = Math.round(d);

        System.out.println(" original: " + s);
        System.out.println("truncated: " + truncated);
        System.out.println("  rounded: " + rounded);
    }
}
```